# Pressing spacebar do not toggle video play or pause

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm trying to set rewrite some shortcut function for `video`. Everything works fine except when pressing spacebar. Here's my code:

```js
let video = document.getElementById("video")
video.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.which == 32 || e.which == 80) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<video id="video" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" width="300" controls></video>
```

Here I use `spacebar` and `P` to toggle play and pause. Using `spacebar` somehow toggled two times while using `P` not.

I try adding event listener of `keyup` and `keypress` to reject the `spacebar` input. But It doesn't work too.

Is there anything about the HTML5 Video I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Since the spacebar by default plays and pauses the video, you have to invert functions in your ternary operator. No need to change them when dealing with the `p` tag.

So the only way is to handle the two different key codes in 2 different `ifs`.

See below the working code snippet.

```js
let video = document.getElementById("video")
video.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.which == 32) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    video.paused ? video.pause() : video.play();
    return false;
  }
  else if (e.which == 80) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<video id="video" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" width="300" controls></video>
```

If you cannot split it, what about nesting the if-else?

```js
let video = document.getElementById("video")
video.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.which == 32 || e.which == 80) {
    if (e.which == 80) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
      return false;
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      video.paused ? video.pause() : video.play();
      return false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<video id="video" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" width="300" controls></video>
```

Comment: That is not the solution. If you try pressing `P`, it's not working now.

Comment: I know I can do in that way but my use case is a little bit annoying. I really can't handle it in two conditions

Comment: @chingcm what about nesting the if-else? see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
let video = document.getElementById("video")
video.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {

  if ([32,80].includes(e.which)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    video.paused ? video.pause() : video.play();
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<video id="video" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" width="300" controls></video>
```